# Inequality based on cubic equation

Tags: inequality, cubics

> If $2x^3+ax^2+bx+4=0$ (where $a$ and $b$ are positive and real) has three real roots,
>  then prove that $a \geq 6\sqrt[3]{2}$.

How to approach this question?

Comment: Please write what you tried.

Comment: Just an observation, one of -1 or -2 is for sure a root

Comment: @Ovi: that is obviously false. $-1$ is a root iff $b-a=2$ and $-2$ is a root iff $2a-b=6$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Sorry, could you point out why that's a problem? My logic went like this: divide both sides by $2$, and the only rational roots are $\pm 1, \pm2$. Because all the terms are positive and the equation has 3 roots, all the roots must be negative. But there are only 2 negative rational possibilities, so the roots cannot all be rational. Since irrational roots come in pairs, we must have 1 rational amd 2 irrational.

Comment: @Ovi: Why not three irrational roots? Take $a=12, b=17$ and check that neither $-1$ or $-2$ is a root.

Comment: Complex roots come into pairs, not irrational roots.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I thought irrational roots did too because I thought you needed that in order to have rational coefficients, but you're right. But how do $b-a=2$ and $2a-b=6$ tell you that my assertion was wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of [Newton's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities) or [MacLaurin's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality) inequalities. If $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\zeta_3$ are the real roots of the given cubic polynomial, by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)
$$\zeta_1+\zeta_2+\zeta_3 = -\frac{a}{2}\qquad\zeta_1\zeta_2+\zeta_1\zeta_3+\zeta_2\zeta_3 = \frac{b}{2}\qquad \zeta_1 \zeta_2\zeta_3=-2$$
and by [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) $\zeta_i<0$. So the polynomial $2x^3-ax^2+bx-4$ has three positive real roots and its elementary symmetric means are
$$ S_1 = \frac{a}{6},\qquad S_2=\frac{b}{6},\qquad S_3=2 $$
where $S_1\geq \sqrt[3]{S_3}$ must hold, leading to $\color{red}{a\geq 6\sqrt[3]{2}}$ as wanted.